# Microsoft App Submission Dashboard page sets AdUnitId to "none"?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I have submitted a application for Windows Phone 8 / 8.1. I have created a pubCenter account from Microsoft Pubcenter and generated the ApplcationId and adUnitId too.

This two fields I have set in the mainPage.xaml so that it display advts.

Now I have submitted the app in the store and it gets published too. But When I visit the dashboard page you can see that pubCenter Application Id and Ad Units is set to none.  [image: Missing entries]

Is there any specifc task I forget to do? Because when I check in PubCenter it shows everything correctly, but I felt that there is some thing went wrong. Can anybody please help me, I am confused of what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So finally I resolved this issue and I thought to post it here so that others will get benefit too.

I have noticed that its a one way process, creating app id in PhoneSubmission page informs Pubcenter, but creating appId in Pubcenter may or may not informs Microsoft's In-App purchase, even if you give the correct app alias name, so its better to follow this technique.

In Windows Phone app submission before you submit the apps, you create the AppUnitId and applicationId in this stage.

I have added two self- describing images of how to do this in step by step ways.

Step 1:

---

[image]

---

Step 2:
[image]

---

After clicking on Generate ad unit, two values will be auto generated, Application id  and AdUnit ID, copy this two values.

Remember that these information ( App alias name etc) will be auto populated to Microsoft pub center, you can visit and check.

Those who started developing their apps thinking that it will display advt they can follow this steps and after that application Id and app unit id is generated they can put those in the xaml, or in code behind and ad will start displaying.

For more helps how to integrate ad in the apps [Click here](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/advertising/adding-microsoft-pubcenter-ads-in-windows-phone-8-apps/)